# Unable to find multiple words on a webpage using richtextbox and documenttext function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, richtextbox

I have this code. Sometimes it finds the word within the webpage and sometimes it does not. I'm not sure what the problem could be. Also the words in input into the richtextbox2.text it only finds the first word, so if I put the first word as "Cookies" and then under that "Milk" , it will only look for "Cookies". Is there a way to make it look for all words inside the richtextbox?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.ToLower.Contains(RichTextBox2.Text.ToLower) Then
        MsgBox("its there")
    Else
        MsgBox("NOT THERE")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for. appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

When there is more than one word in the RichTextBox, it searches for both words at once because they are both in RichTextBox2.Text. You can search for each word or phrase in the RichTextBox one at a time, if they are on separate lines, like this:

```
for each s in RichTextBox2.lines
  If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.ToLower.Contains(s.ToLower) Then
    MsgBox(s & " is there")
  Else
    MsgBox(s & " IS NOT THERE")
  End If
next s
```